# Tree cache in jboss 6.x

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-cache

We are using tree cache in jboss 4.2.x, we are planning to switch to jboss6.x, will jboss 6.x supports tree cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [JBoss Wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/InfinispanIntegrationInAS6):

> As of version 6.0.0.CR1, Infinispan replaced JBoss Cache as the distributed caching technology upon which JBoss AS clustering services are built.

Now, it's possible that you *may* be able to package a [downloaded copy of JBossCache 1.4](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossCacheDownloadsPage) (which is the version that comes with JBossAS 4.2) inside your application and deploy it on JBossAS 6.x, but I suspect this is unlikely to work - JBossCache 1.4 relies on some very old shared JBoss libraries.

I think you're going to have to refactor your code to work with [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan) rather than JBossCache, if you want to migrate from AS 4.2 to 6.x.

Comment: Infinispan also provides a Tree API Module which exposes cache entries in the same structure as TreeCache. This may be helpful if you decide to migrate.   http://community.jboss.org/wiki/TreeAPIModule

Comment: thank for you information reply.thanks a lot, i think this will help a lot.